# Crashlytics crash with proguard

Tags: gradle, proguard, crashlytics, android-proguard, twitter-fabric

I did everything that fabric ask in their documentation:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

But still got this error:

> E/Answers: Failed to submit events task
>                                                                           java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@d2d2a84
>   rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@6b49897[Shutting
>   down, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed
>   tasks = 5]
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2014)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:302)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:527)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:594)
>                                                                               at
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.executeAsync(SourceFile:182)
>                                                                               at
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEvent(SourceFile:168)
>                                                                               at
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEventAsync(SourceFile:44)
>                                                                               at
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.SessionAnalyticsManager.onLifecycle(SourceFile:128)
>                                                                               at
>   com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityStopped(SourceFile:43)
>                                                                               at io.fabric.sdk.android.c.onActivityStopped(SourceFile:126)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStopped(Application.java:232)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.onStop(Activity.java:1620)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(SourceFile:616)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop(SourceFile:172)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1279)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6395)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3824)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3883)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

In addition:
build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.7'
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

My activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
        Fabric.with(this, new Answers(), new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build());
    }
}
```

Opened issue in Twitter forum too:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/e-answers-failed-to-submit-events-task/72921/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly i found my problem. I didn't see it before but, `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` was the problem.
It should be after the initialization of fabric crashlytics while it was one line before.

I solved it by this code:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Order is important!
        // First, start Crashlytics
        Fabric.with(this, new Answers(), new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build());

        // Second, set custom UncaughtExceptionHandler
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandler(this, mDefaultUEH);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
}
```

Comment: Moving setting up the UncaughtEexceptionHandler (in my case for RxJava) to the end of my app's onCreate after everything else worked for me. Thanks