# Fabric Answer Crash when restarting the app after crash

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

In my app I have fabric and DefaultExceptionHandler both set. Order for the same is First Fabric is initialised and started then DefaultExceptionHandler is set.

When any uncaught exception is thrown same is caught in Default Exception and app is restarted after 100 ms. At that point getting the below exception from fabric when activity resumed.

```
E/Answers: Failed to submit events task
       java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@b716997 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@f402784[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 8]
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2049)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:814)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:601)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.executeAsync(AnswersEventsHandler.java:185)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEvent(AnswersEventsHandler.java:171)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEventAsync(AnswersEventsHandler.java:47)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.SessionAnalyticsManager.onLifecycle(SessionAnalyticsManager.java:129)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityStarted(AnswersLifecycleCallbacks.java:26)
           at io.fabric.sdk.android.ActivityLifecycleManager$ActivityLifecycleCallbacksWrapper$1.onActivityStarted(ActivityLifecycleManager.java:111)
           at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:207)
           at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1194)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:595)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1270)
           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6689)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2622)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

E/Answers: Failed to submit events task
       java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@7d90833 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@f402784[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 8]
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2049)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:814)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:601)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.executeAsync(AnswersEventsHandler.java:185)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEvent(AnswersEventsHandler.java:171)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEventAsync(AnswersEventsHandler.java:47)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.SessionAnalyticsManager.onLifecycle(SessionAnalyticsManager.java:129)
           at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityResumed(AnswersLifecycleCallbacks.java:31)
           at io.fabric.sdk.android.ActivityLifecycleManager$ActivityLifecycleCallbacksWrapper$1.onActivityResumed(ActivityLifecycleManager.java:116)
           at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityResumed(Application.java:216)
           at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1255)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:485)
           at com.my.package.BaseActivity.onResume(BaseActivity.java:105)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1291)
           at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6776)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3398)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3461)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2730)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not a supported configuration, but out of curiousity can you provide the debug mode output too? https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html

Comment: This question may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164108/crashlytics-crash-with-proguard